# Tsql translation

Tags: t-sql

Supose I have a table like

```
Id | IsActive
1  | True
2  | False
```

And i want to search items that are active, not active or both

I would like to have a query

declare @ActiveState bit

Select * from myTable where IsActive...

and on my where clause i would like to have something like

```
if(@ActiveState != null)
    myTable.IsActive == @ActiveState
else
    myTable.ActiveState == true || myTable.ActiveState == false
```

but i can't find a way to do this on the same where clause

tks

Comment: can you put into words what you're trying to do? i'm having trouble following your code. How can something (from the example you've given) be active, not active or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from myTable where @ActiveState is null or IsActive = @ActiveState
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE myTable.IsActive  = @ActiveState OR @ActiveState IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

`Where IsActive  = IsNull(@ActiveState, IsActive)`
or
`Where IsActive  = Coalesce(@ActiveState, IsActive)`